# Sharepoint downloads .aspx instead of rendering the page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have all of my js, css, and img files in a Sharepoint Online document library, however when I click index.aspx a download of the index.aspx file is initiated rather than rendering it in the browser. Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried this in the Site Pages library however I cannot upload the index.aspx file because of permission restrictions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. This is called creating a minimal, reproducible example (reprex), a minimal, complete and verifiable example (mcve), or a minimal, workable example (mwe).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to customize a SharePoint page, we can use using SharePoint designer to achieve it.

Open site using SharePoint designer 2013, click "Site Pages", add "ASPX" page, then add some custom CSS, JS, HTML code into the page to achieve your requirement. And set the page to Home page if you want.

[image]

If still not works, we can also create web part page to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your code, how you are downloading.
As of MS, there is no restriction of file upload to the library of list.

[Types of files that cannot be added to a list or library](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Types-of-files-that-cannot-be-added-to-a-list-or-library-30BE234D-E551-4C2A-8DE8-F8546FFBF5B3#ID0EAABAAA=Online)